# Visual C++ 2010 Express Project Templates

Tags: visual-c++

Does Visual C++ 2010 *Express* support custom project templates?

I'm trying to create a simple project template, with no success. The `.vstemplate` file follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Project" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Description>Test</Description>
        <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
        <ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>
        <DefaultName>Test</DefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <Project File="Test.vcxproj" TargetFileName="Test.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
            <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">Test.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$projectname$.c">Source.c</ProjectItem>
        </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

All files referred to by the template file exist; I'll post them if needed.

No matter where I put the zip file containing the template files (`ProjectTemplates`, other places inside the VS installation, running `vcexpress /installvstemplates` and other suggested alternatives), the VS IDE does not detect the project template.

Can anyone provide more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

VS Express does not support 'extensibility' features like custom templates. Note that VS 2013 Community does support them.